# Безопасно ли использовать бесплатные прокси по HTTPS?

Tags: безопасность, vpn, прокси

По-идее безопасно, т.к. шифрование происходит в браузере.

Имеет ли смысл с т.з. безопасности использование платного прокси или создание своей VPN?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от поведения конкретного прокси.

Если при работе через прокси вы получаете оригинальный сертификат целевого сервера - то безопасно. Значит этот прокси трафик не видит и не модифицирует.

Если при работе через прокси вы получаете в ответ левый сертификат - то небезопасно.

Вообщем,  критерий безопасности тот же,  что и при прямой работе с любым сайтом по HTTPS, как через прокси, так и напрямую.

Comment: Я что-то не понял, https прокси это просто http прокси, который позволяет ходить на https?

Comment: @Zergatul нет,  обычно HTTPS прокси это tcp прокси (с протоколом,  позволяющий указать целевой сервер) . Он не анализирует трафик и никак его не меняет. Потому что не может. А HTTP прокси может активно вмешиваться в трафик,  кэшировать его, подменять, сжимать - вообщем, работать с проходящих трафиком как с HTTP.

Comment: Если я отправляю "CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" "Host: google.com", дальше пересылаю бинарный трафик, я не понимаю, почему вы спрашиваете, как сервер поймет куда слать трафик.

Comment: Если бы вы почитали тот RFC, который скинули в комменты, увидели бы там драфт спецификации, по которой разрешаются любые TCP соединения через веб-прокси, с пересылкой любого трафика. https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01

Comment: @Zergatul если честно, я не понимаю - вы хотите узнать какие-то особенности работы http протокола? ну да, есть разные режимы работы - proxy и tunnel. proxy используется *браузерами* для http, пересылает запросы от своего имени. tunnel используется браузерами для https, принимает целевой адрес (через CONNECT) и пересылает сырой траффик. обычно прокси-сервер без поддержки tunnel (ssl tunneling) называют "HTTP-прокси" (т.к. он не может https), а прокси с поддержкой ssl tunneling (по сути, что-угодно tunneling) называют "HTTPS-прокси", (т.к. HTTP прокси который поддерживает HTTPS - длинно)

Comment: @Zergatul только все это не имеет отношения к вопросу. топикастер спросил, безопасно ли использовать HTTPS (HTTP прокси с поддержкой туннелирования). Ответ - да, безопасно, если он не лезет в туннелируемый траффик (что обнаруживается по подмене сертификата). Сорри - предыдущие сообщения писал с телефона, кратко и с опечатками :)

Comment: А я вот нашёл статью что готовые VPN всё таки лучше не использовать. https://gist.github.com/joepie91/5a9909939e6ce7d09e29